# Receiving Error: Entity of type 'flow' named 'xxxxxxxxxxxx' cannot be found when doing an sfdx force:source:pull command

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I have made edits (Cloned/deleted old version) to a process builder in a scratch org and when I perform the sfdx force:source:pull command in GitBash I receive

> Error: "Entity of type 'flow' named 'xxxxxxxxxxxx' cannot be found".

This is a new error that we weren't receiving a week ago. I have checked the files within the Flows folder in Force-app and they do exist.

Any assistance or ideas on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to resolve this issue by updating by sfdx-cli package to the latest version using NPM (npm i sfdx-cli@latest -g) and manually changing the sourceApiVersion value from 43.0 to 44.0 in my sfdx-project.json file.  You might start with the sourceApiVersion change first and see if that fixes it, since I'm not sure the CLI update was necessary.

Comment: Yeah as stated, updating the api version in sfdx-project.json fixed this issue for me (without needing to update the sfdx-cli package to the latest version using NPM).